# Oracle/PHP oci_fetch_all() issue

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Pretty new to PHP using Oracle.  I'm following examples online.  I'm using this example 1 from the official site. My issue is, it displays all the records like I want, but it's missing the column/field names.  Does anyone now how to alter this so that it includes the headers? (ex, my employee table would have... First Name, Last Name....) Thanks

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employee');
oci_execute($stid);

$nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);

echo "$nrows rows fetched<br>\n";
var_dump($res);

// Pretty-print the results
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
foreach ($res as $col) {
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach ($col as $item) {
    echo "    <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "")."</td>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Did you pay attention to the result from the `var_dump($res)` line? That clearly shows how the array is, so you can extract the info accordingly.

Comment: I'm extremely new to this...I'm basically learning by trial and error right now, I just need an example...

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rude, but if you're so new that you can't even tell what's going on with the `var_dump($res)` output, I think you may need to go through [some](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) [basic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) [document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) first.

Comment: It doesn't sound rude, but I was in a pinch, I didn't have time to do the research, hence, why I asked the question.  No offense to you, but I asked the question so I could get it done quickly not be redirected, I'm sure if I spent long enough researching I would have figured it out.  It took me long enough manipulating this example to understand it, I just didn't have time to figure out the columns as well.  But thanks any way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMS(I haven't worked with them all so I can't say "all") systems have a separate table that stores this sort of meta information, so you'd want to query it. In Oracle, it's stored as a dictionary, probably in some sort of table header data or meta info (I really don't know Oracle's underlying structure well) and it's called user_tab_columns

So what do ya do? Query it as though it were a table.

```
SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns WHERE TABLE_NAME='employee'
```

However, I don't know why you'd want to query this after the fact given your code, as you already know the column names and could easily just hardcode them in.

Comment: Thanks. For clarification, do I replace this with my current sql statement?  Honestly, I just want them attached to the output, you said I could hardcode them in...do you have an example including this in the sample code above? I would really appreciate it.